How do I install custom GO plugins on Zabbix Agent 2 for Windows?
I am trying to follow the documentations of Zabbix that teaches us how to install custom Go Plugins on Zabbix Agent 2 - But they only teach how to do this on Linux agents only...
On Windows, there is little to no instructions on how to do this on Windows.
Documentations:
https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/mssql
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/extensions/plugins
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/appendix/config/zabbix_agent2_plugins/mssql_plugin
I tried following the documentations but I was'nt able to got it right.
I had success doing it on Linux tho... The only problem I am having is with Windows.
